# Kendo datgrid not sending sort field parameter to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo datagrid that retrieves data through an ajax transport. The paging features work perfectly. However, the control keeps sending a blank sort field parameter when clicking a column heading to sort the data.

Interestingly, the control still sends the sort direction, just not the field name.

I’ve set sortable to true, DataSource, set serverPaging to true, and defined data types for each column. Is there anything else I am missing?

Unfortunately I can’t post code right now, but can put something together if I can’t resolve this through something simple.

Here is the post that's being sent to the web service:

```
endDate: "10/31/2013 12:00 AM"
page: 1
pageSize: 20
skip: 0
sort: [{field:[], dir:asc, compare:null}]
    0: {field:[], dir:asc, compare:null}
       compare: null
       dir: "asc"
       field: []
startDate: "10/1/2013 12:00 AM"
take: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was caused by the way in which I was creating the DataSource.schema.model.fields object. Initially I had passed a multidimensional array, like:

```
var fields = [
    fields['Field1'] = [];
    fields['Field1']['type'] = 'string';
    fields['Field1']['editable'] = false;
    fields['Field1']['sortable'] = true;
];
```

Changing this to key/value pairs solved the sorting issue:

```
var fields = {
  Field1: {
     type: 'string',
     editable: false,
     sortable: true
  }
};
```

the fields object is then passed to DataSource.schema.model.fields.